# Issue with XML Modify

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to generate an attribute using XML Modify of SQL server.
The Attribute i am trying to generate is

```
HRef="#'2'!A1"
```

The Query that I am using is

```
set @xml.modify('declare default element namespace  "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                declare namespace ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                declare namespace x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
                insert attribute  ss:HRef {"#''sql:variable(""@worksheets"")''!A1"}      
                into (/Workbook/Worksheet[1]/Table/Row[sql:variable("@worksheets")]/Cell)[1]');
```

The **sql:variable("@worksheets")** is coming from a loop variable. and its value are 1, 2 , 3 for each loop.
So the values that  want in that attribute should be

```
HRef="#'1'!A1"
HRef="#'2'!A1"
HRef="#'3'!A1"
```

Now the issue is, the value is not changing in XML. If i am using following query

```
insert attribute  ss:HRef {"#''sql:variable(""@worksheets"")''!A1"}      
                into (/Workbook/Worksheet[1]/Table/Row[sql:variable("@worksheets")]/Cell)[1]');
```

The Attribute that is generated in XML is

> ss:HRef="#'sql:variable("@worksheets")'!A1"

which is worng, it should be generated as

> HRef="#'2'!A1"

As per my understanding the value of sql:variable("@worksheets") is not getting replaced.
If i put some hard coded value instead of sql:variable("@worksheets") the values are visible correctly in xml.
Can any one please suggest what wrong i am doing.

Sample XML that i am using is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <Styles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
            <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
            <Borders/>
            <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
            <Interior/>
            <NumberFormat/>
            <Protection/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s62">
            <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s63" ss:Name="Hyperlink">
            <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#0000FF" ss:Underline="Single"/>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
    <Worksheet xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="1">
        <Table xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="125">
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
            <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Worksheet #</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:HRef="#'sql:variable(&quot;@worksheets&quot;)'!A1">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
    <Worksheet xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="2">
        <Table xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="125">
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
            <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Audit ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Audit Subcategory ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">2</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">105076</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">10</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">2</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
    <Worksheet xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="3">
        <Table xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="125">
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
            <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Audit ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Audit Subcategory ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">3</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
    <Worksheet xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="4">
        <Table xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="125">
            <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1"/>
            <Row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Audit ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Audit Subcategory ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">4</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Could we have a demonstraton value for @xml please?

Comment: @RossPresser , Thanks for asking. I have modified the question with sample xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that here

```
insert attribute  ss:HRef {"#''sql:variable(""@worksheets"")''!A1"}
```

it seems as if you expect xquery to "magically" concatenate those strings. You need to specify it. The fact that you needed to put extra quotes and apostrophes implies that it is considering it as a single string.

Your insert should look like this

```
set @xml.modify('declare default element namespace  "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                declare namespace ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
                declare namespace x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
                insert attribute ss:HRef {concat("#", sql:variable("@worksheets") cast as xs:string?, "!A1")}
                into (/Workbook/Worksheet[1]/Table/Row[sql:variable("@worksheets")]/Cell)[1]');
```

I'm assuming that `@worksheets` is a numeric variable; that's the reason for the `cast as xs:string`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the correct answer. That was the mistake i was doing.